# How do I write the toString() and peek() functions in an implementation of a Linked Stack?

Tags: java

> > I have comments below each block of code.

```
public class LinearNode<T>
{
    private LinearNode<T> next;
    private T element;
 
    /**
     * Creates an empty node.
     */
    public LinearNode()
    {
        next = null;
        element = null;
    }
 
    /**
     * Creates a node storing the specified element.
     * @param elem element to be stored
     */
    public LinearNode(T elem)
    {
        next = null;
        element = elem;
    }
 
    /**
     * Returns the node that follows this one.
     * @return reference to next node
     */
    public LinearNode<T> getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
 
    /**
     * Sets the node that follows this one.
     * @param node node to follow this one
     */
    public void setNext(LinearNode<T> node)
    {
        next = node;
    }
 
    /**
     * Returns the element stored in this node.
     * @return element stored at the node
     */
    public T getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }
 
    /**
     * Sets the element stored in this node.
     * @param elem element to be stored at this node
     */
    public void setElement(T elem)
    {
        element = elem;
    }
}
```

> Above is the actual class of the node itself in which you have getters and setters for specific characteristics of the node in which you can get and set their attributes. Each node has a next "pointer" and has a constructor to put a element into.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Represents a linked implementation of a stack.
 */
public class LinkedStack<T> 
{
    private int count;  
    private LinearNode<T> top; 

    /**
     * Creates an empty stack.
     */
    public LinkedStack()
    {
        count = 0;
        top = null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack.
     * @param element element to be pushed on stack
     */
    public void push(T element)
    {
        LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);

        temp.setNext(top);
        top = temp;
        count++;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the element at the top of this stack and returns a
     * reference to it. 
     * @return element from top of stack
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the stack is empty
     */
    public T pop() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");

        T result = top.getElement();
        top = top.getNext();
        count--;

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the element at the top of this stack.
     * The element is not removed from the stack.  
     * @return element on top of stack
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the stack is empty  
     */
    public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if(isEmpty()) { 
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");
        }
    
        T node =top.getElement();
        return node;
    }
    /**
     * Returns true if this stack is empty and false otherwise. 
     * @return true if stack is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if(count==0) {return true;}
        else {

            return false;}
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this stack.
     * @return number of elements in the stack
     */
    public int size()
    {
        
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this stack. 
     * @return string representation of the stack
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        
    
        
        //not exactly sure
        


    }
}
```

> This is the LinkedStack Class in which implements the LinearNode class in the previous code block. It essentially forms the linked list using the `push(...)`method above to link each node together. I am having trouble with my `peek()` and `toString(...)`method. It provides a way to efficiently link nodes together regardless of the type of node.
>
> > My implementation is shown below in which I am using a Scanner to take in user input and then using another Scanner to take the string of the user input and put each individual word into a created **LinearNode**. I use my various methods from the **LinkedStack** to implement and link the nodes. My **GOAL** is to use all of my methods in the LinkedStack Class.
> > Below is my implementation

````
import java.util.*;
public class Sentence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence;
//Takes in user input
        Scanner userInput= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please type in sentence.");

sentence=userInput.nextLine();


userInput.close();

//Instantiates a new LinkedStack which takes in type of LinearNode
LinkedStack <LinearNode> Stack=new LinkedStack <LinearNode>();

//Scanner that grabs each individual workd from string
Scanner checker = new Scanner(sentence);
while(checker.hasNext()) {
    String x =checker.next();
    LinearNode<String> words=new LinearNode<String>(x);
    Stack.push(words);  //pushes the new created node with the individual word ```x``` onto the ```Stack```  
    
}
//other methods 
System.out.println(Stack.size());
System.out.println("Emptiness: "+Stack.isEmpty());
System.out.println("we peek on "+Stack.peek());// not sure how to get the actual node

System.out.println("The to string method is: "+Stack.toString());//want this to work correctly
        

System.out.println("we pop "+Stack.pop());

System.out.println(Stack.size());


checker.close();






    }

}
````

> The output is:

```
Please type in sentence.
Hello world  
2 
Emptiness: false
we peek on LinearNode@6f496d9f

we pop LinearNode@6f496d9f
1
```

> The individual integers is the size() method.
>
> > Problem:
> > When I use the `peek()` method I seem to be getting the address in which I think I would rather return the actual node.
> > And I cannot figure out how to get the Objects from the nodes from the LinkedStack to print out with my `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

> It provides a way to efficiently

These things are not efficient on modern hardware no matter what you do, so nevermind that :) - but that's not your question, so let's move on.

Your LinearNode and LinearStack classes work great, but note that LinearNode is **entirely an inside job**: LinearStack makes them, and queries them. In fact, you should make LinearNode non-public to highlight this fact. It's there for the benefit of LinearStack, and other code has zero business messing with em. For example, if someone I get a reference to a LinearNode that is in a stack, I can call `.setNext` and break your list. For example, that doesn't magically update the `count` in any list(s) that the node is in, or I could have multiple stack objects that each have the same node someplace, causing really bizarre effects if you start popping in one stack (as that will mess with the other... without updating count).

That's all you're doing wrong here: You have a stack of LinearNode objects. The stack is generified, it can store whatever you want it to store, so it is dutifully doing precisely what you command, and internally it has a `LinearNode<LinearNode<String>>`. Yes, that's a node *of a node*. Not what you want.

So, **don't do**:

```
String x = checker.next();
LinearNode<String> words = new LinearNode<String>(x);
stack.push(words);
```

Follow the code through: the second line creates a linearnode then calls stack push. Go look at that code: First thing it does? Create a LinearNode object. That's not right - 1 pushed element should mean 1 created node object.

**do**:

```
String x = checker.next();
stack.push(x);
```

Also, you have declared your stack to be a 'stack of nodes'. That's.. not what you want. You want it to be a 'stack of strings'. Again, `LinearNode` should be absolutely nowhere in your main class, it should be invisible and non-existent to all code.. except `LinearStack` which needs it to function. Declare it as a `LinearStack<String>`.